# HTML Highlighting Tags On Hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, tags

Given the following `html`:

```
This is a test to
<cpos data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1"> 
  highlight only this portion of text 
</cpos> and not this
```

My task is to highlight only the `cpos` portion. I am able to highlight a `div` class on my own, but a little confused on how to do this. I am using `javascript` along with a `css` style

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No javascript needed, just use css [:hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover)

```css
cpos:hover{
  background:yellow;
  }
```

```html
This is a test to<cpos data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1"> highlight only this portion of text </cpos> and not this
```

**Update**

> If I had multiple `cpos` tags with different ids and wanted to
>   highlight an individual one on hover

Simply target each individual id with `#`

```css
#MyId:hover{
  background:yellow;
  }
```

```html
This is a test to<cpos data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1"> highlight only this portion of text </cpos> and not this

This is a test to<cpos id="MyId" data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1"> highlight only this portion of text </cpos> and not this
```

> Also, is there anyway you could show me how to do this using
>   javascirpt?

Use `onmouseover` and `onmouseout` events

```html
This is a test to<cpos data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1" onmouseover="this.style.background='yellow'" onmouseout="this.style.background=''"> highlight only this portion of text </cpos> and not this
```

> Is there a way to do it similarly to your javascript example but
>   without changing the cpos tag attributes?

Yes, iterate through them and attach programmatically

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('cpos');
for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++){
  elements[i].onmouseover = function(){
    this.style.background = 'yellow';
    }
  elements[i].onmouseout = function(){
    this.style.background = '';
    }
  }
```

```html
This is a test to
<cpos data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1">
  highlight only this portion of text
</cpos>and not this This is a test to
<cpos data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1">
  highlight only this portion of text
</cpos>and not this This is a test to
<cpos data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1">
  highlight only this portion of text
</cpos>and not this
```

Comment: Two questions for you, and thanks for the quick help!
If I had multiple cpos tags with different id's adn wanted to highlight an individual one on hover, how would I do that.
Also, is there anyway you could show me how to do this using javascirpt?

Comment: @Trying2LearnMath, sure, what are the questions?

Comment: Great thank you. The way this is set up, I will go to a page in which there is anywhere from 1 to 100 comments all with a cpos tag and a unique id. I understand that the way you described requires a fixed 'MyId' for each cpos tag, correct? Is there anyway to allow individual highlighting for each cpos tag regardless of Id number

Comment: @Trying2LearnMath, it can be any id, not necessarily 'MyId'. Regarding individual highlighting, Id is the easiest way

Comment: I am sorry, one last question. The before code was very helpful! Did not realize it was as simple as that.
Is there a way to do it similarly to your javascript example but without changing the cpos tag attributes? The way things are set up as of now, I am not able to edit the attributes.

Comment: Yes! Thank you for the lengthy assistance! This is definitely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS. Make use of a `class`.

CSS:

```
.highlight:hover{ //Use HOVER
    background-color:yellow;
}
```

HTML:

```
This is a test to<cpos class="highlight" data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1"> highlight only this portion of text </cpos> and not this
```

Comment: Is it required to make use of a class? 
The way everything is set up right now, this is the exact code that is sent to me and would be helpful if I did not have to classify it as a class.

Comment: @Trying2LearnMath It is not mandatory, however I always prefer a class as it shows your intentions.

Answer (score 0):

:hoverWhat you have to do is assign a class to the cpos, in other scenario you can even use SPAN that are like 
    this is  big .. the end

For your code, add the class as follow:

```
This is a test to<cpos class="highlight" data-idcpos="10" data-comment="1"> highlight only this portion of text </cpos> and not this
```

in CSS

```
.hightlight:hover{
     background-color: yellow;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a good highlighting example With Animation for You :)
using CSS :
No javascript needed

Your CSS:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  background: #2c3e50;
  display: flex;
}

.card {
  width: 350px;
  padding: 30px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  margin: auto;
  transition: .3s ease;
  box-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  transform: translateY(-10px) scale(1.02);
}
.card:hover .entry-title {
  background-position: -100% 0;
}

.entry-title {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 50%, #16a085 50%);
  background-size: 200%;
  background-position: 0 0;
  display: inline;
  transition: .5s ease-in-out;
  font-family: raleway, arial, sans-serif;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
.entry-title cpos {
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
<h1 class="entry-title">
<cpos><a>This text will be highlighted when hovered</a></cpos>
</h1>
</div>
```

and here it is on JSfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ebramatef/Lfd98v9m/